# Speed up the process of loading a .exe file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, exe

I created a java application using `Eclipse`.
Then I created an executable `.jar` file, choosing "***Package*** required libraries into generated JAR".
Eventually, I created a `.exe` file using [Lauch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

The problem is that this `.exe` file takes forever for opening the application and executing the "on startup" statements (which only take few seconds when I run the application from eclipse). I believe that the problem is that all the required libraries are packed into the `.jar` file, and it need to unpack them.
Unfortunately, to *pack the required library into the generated JAR* is my only chance, since the application seems not to read some required libraries (e.g. `gluegen-rt.jar`) if they are **extracted** into the generated file.

Anyone has an idea about how to speed up the unpack process? Maybe passing some commands to the JVM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: not creating a exe would be my first step

Comment: @Stultuske This comment does not really help the OP.

Comment: @Stultuske What should I do? I'm creating the exe because I need to run the .jar with a specific JRE.